# How do I tidied writing articles in Blogger?

Tags: html, web, blogger

My difficulty in writing articles because there is no alignment of a "colon". Is there software that can help me tidy up the text.

This is an example of an article I wrote

[image: xxxxxx]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via [table element in HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

An example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Bassam

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the [<table> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) in the **HTML** tab of the post editor.

An example with the colon aligned would look like -

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Nama</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>Zain Javadd Malik</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tanggal Lahir</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>12 Januari 1993</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tempat Lahir</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>Bradford, West Yorkshire, Inggris</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pendidikan</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>Sekolah Tinggi Tong di Bradford</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pekerjaan</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>Penyanyi, penulis lagu</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tahun aktif</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>2010 - sekarang</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Album Pertama</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>Mind of Mine</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tanggal rilis</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>25 Maret 2016</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Prayag Verma :D